# difference between stripe-php and stripe-cartalyst APIs when using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I want to use stripe payment gateway for my php application developed using laravel.I found this https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/1.0 package which makes using stripe with laravel easy, but I am afraid if it will be able to provide me each and very api that is mentioned on the official php API on the stripe website ?

For eg the code to retrieve my account balance using stripe official php doc is :

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

\Stripe\Balance::retrieve();
```

while to do same in cartalyst-stripe is:

```
Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

$balance = Stripe::balance()->current();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Cartalyst/stripe-laravel` is a Platform-Agnostic package

Instead, you should be using [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing)

Then your `User` model will get a `billable` trait. So you can attach `Stripe` functionality directly to your customer.

Comment: I have checked that as well, but I think it only supports subscription based payments and in my case, I need to do single payments and refunds as well.

Comment: @JitenderYadav That is entirely not true, as we personally use it for single payments and refunds. You just need to implement your own traits extending the package and interfacing with the Stripe API.